# How to convert MongoDB results from $dateToString operation to Java object

Tags: java, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have obtained "date only" results from ISODate datatype from my mongo document using following query :

```
db.getCollection('tournamentactivity').aggregate( [ 
{
    $project:{
            "yearMonthDay": 
                { 
                    "$dateToString" : 
                    { 
                        "format" : "%Y-%m-%d", 
                        "date" : "$activityDate" 
                    } 
                },                   
                "tid" : 1,
                "dayActivity.type" : 1    
           }
 },
 {
     $match:{
          $and : [
            { "tid" : "12345678" },
            { "yearMonthDay" : "2017-11-05" }             
         ]


      }      
}] )
```

All good till here. But I am trying to convert the same in Java object as I have to send the same in my response type.

I have followed this tutorial : [Projections](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations) and tried to do the same in my Java code as below :

```
ProjectionOperation projectToMatchModel = project().
            andExpression("format").as("%Y-%m-%d").
            andExpression("date").as("$activityDate");
```

I have written Aggregation operations prior to this, but I have no idea how to convert this result/query in Java code.

Can anyone guide me where am I going wrong and how to use the same in 
*Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            );* method ?

Thanks.

**FYI** : I have no idea on converting this query in my aggregation object and I **might** be wrong on choice of projection operations. Please go easy on me if I am wrong !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

Add below imports

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Fields.field;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Fields.from;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.DateOperators;
```

Option 1 ( Using extension method )

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
       project(from(field("dayActivity.type", "dayActivity.type"), 
                    field("tid"))).
               and("activityDate").dateAsFormattedString("%Y-%m-%d").as("yearMonthDay"),
       match(where("yearMonthDay").is("2017-11-05").and("tid").is("12345678"))
);
```

Option 2 ( Using Aggregation Expression )

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
       project(from(field("dayActivity.type", "dayActivity.type"), 
                    field("tid"))).
               and(DateOperators.dateOf("activityDate").toString("%Y-%m-%d")).as("yearMonthDay"),
       match(where("yearMonthDay").is("2017-11-05").and("tid").is("12345678"))
);
```